# Best strategy for Multiple Blindfolded 3x3 Rubik's Cube event (WCA)

Tags: strategy, rubiks-cube, mechanical-puzzles, twisty-puzzles

The MBLD event is quite hard on the technique and the memory, testing the 3x3 Blindfolded method.

The cube placement strategy as discussed by few officials stand at: [Cube Placement](https://github.com/thewca/wca-regulations/issues/444)

The other strategy that can be optimized is the way in which the review is done , and now the cube is divided into smaller groups of cube , that can be collectively memorised at once.

[image: MBLD event: Jakarta Opem]

So, what is the best strategy using the concept of economy of movement?

Comment: Hmm, what are you asking then?

Comment: I am asking for scientifically finding out the strategy , using the concept of economy of movement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_motion_economy

Comment: OK just edited ur question so that it becomes clearer (have to wait until it is peer viewed though) :D

Comment: Okay cool , I hope you know about what MBLD (Multiple Blindfolded ) exactly is?

Comment: Well, I'm not that good in solving a rubik's cube blindfolded (up to 1 minute or even more sometimes) but I do quite well with the normal CFOP method (around 15 - 20 seconds). Anyways, to answer ur question, I do know it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a regulation change, then **the most efficient method to place cubes will depend on the solver's strategy for memorising cubes and reviewing their memo**. There won't will be an "optimal" way which can be written in the regulations that will suit everybody. The regulations currently ask for cubes to arranged [as close to a square as possible](https://www.worldcubeassociation.org/regulations/#H1a3) and I think this is good enough: easy to implement and easy to enforce.

If you are considering arranging your cubes at the start of your attempt then considering optimal layouts is unlikely to help. A theoretically perfect arrangement will not even save you 10 seconds, which is more time than you'd take rearranging even just half a dozen cubes.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the answer. The top solvers like Shivam Bansal and Graham Siggins arrange the cubes in packs of 8.